# cpanm force install fails to Build and test Alien::OpenSSL on WSL

Tags: linux, perl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cpan, cpanm

I am new to perl and I have having some trouble installing some packages on my WSL2 Ubuntu20.04 distro.
The comand that I am runnig on my machine is:

```
sudo cpanm --force Net::RFC3161::Timestamp
```

**Output of the code is:**

```sh
--> Working on Net::RFC3161::Timestamp
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/A/AK/AKHUETTEL/Net-RFC3161-Timestamp-0.020.tar.gz ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Alien::OpenSSL
--> Working on Alien::OpenSSL
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/P/PL/PLICEASE/Alien-OpenSSL-0.12.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Alien-OpenSSL-0.12 ... OK
Building and testing Alien-OpenSSL-0.12 ... FAIL
! Installing Alien::OpenSSL failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1648856748.7098/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Alien::OpenSSL' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for Net-RFC3161-Timestamp-0.020.
```

I am tryng to solve this problem and I could not find any specifical solution yet, suppose I am missing something.

**Additional information**

output of `uname -a` :

```sh
Linux WINDELL-CRVRRA1 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

output of `cpanm --version`

```sh
cpanm (App::cpanminus) version 1.7045 (/usr/local/bin/cpanm)
perl version 5.030000 (/usr/bin/perl)

  %Config:
    archname=x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
    installsitelib=/usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0
    installsitebin=/usr/local/bin
    installman1dir=/usr/share/man/man1
    installman3dir=/usr/share/man/man3
    sitearchexp=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0
    sitelibexp=/usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0
    vendorarch=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30
    vendorlibexp=/usr/share/perl5
    archlibexp=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30
    privlibexp=/usr/share/perl/5.30
  %ENV:
    PERL5LIB=/home/indiano/perl5/lib/perl5
    PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=/home/indiano/perl5
    PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base "/home/indiano/perl5"
    PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/indiano/perl5
  @INC:
    FatPacked::93979654366464=HASH(0x557957ea2500)
    /home/indiano/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
    /home/indiano/perl5/lib/perl5
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30
    /usr/share/perl/5.30
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
```

Thanks for the support

Comment: *"Installing Alien::OpenSSL failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1648856748.7098/build.log for details."* Please include relevant information about the problem from the `build.log` file

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` with `cpanm` when you are using [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) ?

Comment: I tried to install `Net::RFC3161::Timestamp` on Windows 11, WSL with Ubuntu 20.04 and here the dependency `Alien::Build` fails to install. Submitted bug report [here](https://github.com/PerlAlien/Alien-Build/issues/302)

Comment: Came to to the conclusions that some basic packages were missing, I will write soon an answer .

Comment: Don't use `--force`!!!